# Reduce whitespace in between my page body and the line below my navigation in wordpress custom page?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

http://rockstarrose.com/shop/hometest/#

Can't figure out where to target or place css. Is it in my theme file somewhere?

Just want the space to be halved above the text where it says "Flat Rate[...]Us"

Also can't figure out how to add code to this stupid box.

You can download a txt file of the code of the wordpress page here from my dropbox.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1355646/Chameleon%20sharing/Rockstarrose/wordpresspage.rtf

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top margin from `.site-content`.  The WebKit inspector/Firebug are your friends when it comes to things like this.